# Shipping in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

Is it possible to apply a shipping cost to the cart before a customer enters their shipping address?

The site I am working on has a fixed shipping rate of £3.50 for UK orders under £22. If the order value is over £22 then the shipping is free.

Anyone based in and shipping to, Europe has a set rate based on weight of the order.

Is it possible to set the initial base shipping cost to the cart screen before checkout and then change the shipping cost and method when the customer adds a shipping address during checkout?

What is the best approach for setting these shipping rates in the Control Panel, and how to apply these in the cart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Shipping Country and Method for the Cart screen](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16909/setting-shipping-country-and-method-for-the-cart-screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, it is not possible.  The much longer answer I will add to your other question:

[Setting Shipping Country and Method for the Cart screen](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16909/setting-shipping-country-and-method-for-the-cart-screen)